# Align divs on one line and center horizontally

Tags: html, css

All three boxes (box1,box2 and box3) should be on the same line and aligned center.

[Here is a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jctu0az/) of the below:

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
#container1 {
  border: 2px dashed magenta;
}
#box1,
#box2,
#box3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  postition: fixed;
}
#box1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
#box2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: left;
}
#box3 {
  border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container1">
    <div id="box1">
      <p>Box 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
      <p>Box 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
      <p>Box 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update: 
If you run into some single line gap problem, please consider this post: [fighting line-gaps with inline-block](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)**

I made some modification on your demo, you can simply do it with:

`display: inline-block;`

instead of using

`float: left;`.

adding

`text-align: center;`

on top container helps you center its child.

[revised demo / sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7jctu0az/6/)

**Much cleaner code**

```css
#wrapper{
    background-color: lightcyan;
}

#container1{
    border: 2px dashed magenta;
    text-align: center;
}

#container1 > div{
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#box1{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box2{
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#box3{
    border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="box1">
            <p>Box 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
            <p>Box 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box3">
            <p>Box 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could also address [the inline gap problem](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) and add a simpler way to target the direct child divs: `#container1 > div {
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}`

Answer (score 1):

try this.

[see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/g1L9xoba/)

html

```
<div id="main">

    <div id="container">

        <div id="box1">
            <p>Box 1</p>
        </div>

        <div id="box2">
            <p>Box 2</p>
        </div>

        <div id="box3">
            <p>Box 3</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#main{
    background-color: lightpink;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:15px;
}

#container{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 304px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:5px;
}

#container:after{
    content: '';
    clear:both;
    display: table;
}

#box1,#box2,#box3{
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#box2{
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}

p{
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these
**from**

```
#container1{
    border: 2px dashed magenta;
}
```

**to**

```
#container1{
    border: 2px dashed magenta;
    display: table;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

also add float left to your third box like so,

```
#box3{
    border: 1px solid brown;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/7jctu0az/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrapper{
    background-color: lightcyan;
}

#container1{
    border: 2px dashed magenta;
    text-align: center;
}

#box1,#box2,#box3{
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#box1{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box2{
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#box3{
    border: 1px solid brown;
}



<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="box1">
            <p>Box 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
            <p>Box 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box3">
            <p>Box 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add floats to the boxes. Also need to set a width to the container1 which will allow it to be center aligned via margins. I also added overflow auto to both container1 & wrapper to clear the floats

```
#wrapper{
    background-color: lightcyan;
    border: 2px dashed magenta;    
    overflow: auto;
}

#container1{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#box1,#box2,#box3{
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#box1{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box2{
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#box3{
    border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jctu0az/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can have this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7jctu0az/7/

Just use  tag of HTML and your problem will get solved.

```css
#wrapper{
    background-color: lightcyan;
}

#container1{
    border: 2px dashed magenta;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#box1,#box2,#box3{
    
    display:inline-block;
}

#box1{
    border: 1px solid red;
    
}

#box2{
    border: 1px solid green;
   
}

#box3{
    border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container1">
        <center>
        <div id="box1">
            <p>Box 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
            <p>Box 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box3">
            <p>Box 3</p>
        </div>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the chance you wanted the outer most container to have the dashed outline I created this one for you as well - I think this might have been what you were wanting.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jctu0az/9/)

Basically just floats all 3 dives, margin: 0 auto for center container, and clearfix for outer most container:

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are several things you can fix to make this work as described. I've added general descriptions for what each property does in getting you to your answer with the hope that you will be able to understand what is going on, rather than just copy/paste in an answer that works (not to say that's always a bad thing, but learning is important too ;) )

**For `#container1`**

1. You need to define a width. I've set it to the total width of the
   three child divs at 300px. Normally this wouldn't work because you'd
   have to account for the added width due to the div borders, but we
   can get around this with the box-sizing property (later).
2. Set your margin to auto. This will in effect center the container
   div on the page (making it easier to center the other elements).
3. Add a property of overflow:auto; This will allow the dashed lines
   to flow around the floating elements that are nested inside. Without
   this, it will appear as though they are just one single line.

**For `#box1,#box2,#box3`**

- Add the property `box-sizing` and set it to `border-box`. This will then calculate the width of all three of the boxes to include padding, border, and margin spacing in the width of 100px which you are specifying. Note that the box-sizing property is a CSS3 property and won't display appropriately for older browsers ([see here for a list of supported browsers and how to use the property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)). In this case, the last element will be forced to display underneath the other two elements. If this happens you can calculate the added pixel width of the borders (6 additional pixels in this case) to fit things properly again.

**For `#box3`**

- You need to add `float:left;` again to this.

Here's an updated JSFiddle with your modified code http://jsfiddle.net/iandbanks/7jctu0az/11/

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Code](http://jsfiddle.net/7jctu0az/13/)

Remove `float: left` for `#box1` and `#box2`

CSS

```
#container1{
    border: 2px dashed magenta;
    display: table; /*Add this*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*Add this*/
}

#box1,#box2,#box3{
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    display: table-cell /*Add this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //use display:table in  #box1,#box2,#box3;
    #wrapper {
      background-color: lightcyan;
    }
    #container1 {
      border: 2px dashed magenta;
    }
    #box1,#box2,#box3 {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      postition: fixed;
    display:table;
    }
    #box1 {
      border: 1px solid red;
      float: left;
    }
    #box2 {
      border: 1px solid green;
      float: left;
    }
    #box3 {
      border: 1px solid brown;

    }
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="container1">
        <div id="box1">
          <p>Box 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
          <p>Box 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="box3">
          <p>Box 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Consider explaining your solution rather then just posting huge piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:table` to `#box3`:

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
#container1 {
  border: 2px dashed magenta;
}
#box1,
#box2,
#box3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  /*position: fixed;*/
}
#box1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
#box2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: left;
}
#box3 {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  display:table;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container1">
    <div id="box1">
      <p>Box 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
      <p>Box 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
      <p>Box 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```